# this.getClass usage in Scala traits

Tags: scala, traits

Can somebody explain why this code works in that way? I wanted to make my own proof of concept Loggable trait. The plan was to instantiate a logger instance in order that inherited classes do not have to do that work. But as I can see this is not what I wanted.

Here is the code:

```scala
package hu.jonas.simple

trait Loggable {
  val logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  def whoAmI = {
    logger.info(this.getClass.getName)
  }
}

class Service extends Loggable {
  def answer = {
    whoAmI
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  new Service().answer
}
```

It produced the following log message:

```
Jan 25, 2013 2:02:07 PM hu.jonas.simple.Loggable$class whoAmI
INFO: hu.jonas.simple.Service
```

Why do the two this.getClass.getName differ? And moreover what should I need to write when I instantiate the logger in order to get this:

```
Jan 25, 2013 2:02:07 PM hu.jonas.simple.Service whoAmI
INFO: hu.jonas.simple.Service
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code both occurences of `getClass.getName` return the same value. But the logger, when formatting the output message, is simply using the source class (that it can know by inspecting the stack) instead of the logger's name (which in your case corresponds to `getClass.getName`). So the logger when outputing the header for the log record is actually using the name of the class where the call to `log` is done, while the content of the log message is the name runtime class of the instance. So this is like a *static* vs *runtime* type issue. If you're wondering where `Loggable$class` comes from, it just so happens that the method implementations in a trait named `T` are located in a JVM class named `T$class`.

And now for an illustration. In the below code I change the log handler so as to erase the information from the source class. This forces the logger to use the logger name instead of the source class name, and you get back the behaviour that you expected.

```
import java.util.logging._
trait Loggable {
  val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  logger.getParent.getHandlers.foreach{ handler => 
    val formatter = handler.getFormatter
    handler.setFormatter( new java.util.logging.Formatter {
      def format( record: LogRecord ) = {
        record.setSourceClassName( null )
        formatter.format( record )
      }
    })
  }


  def whoAmI = {
    logger.info(this.getClass.getName)
  }
}

class Service extends Loggable {
  def answer = {
    whoAmI
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  new Service().answer
}
```

Now, to properly fix your issue, there is a property named `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` that you can set to change the default log formatting. Use it to have the log use the logger name instead of the source class. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html.
Note that it requires Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at there is the method that called the logger, not necessarily the class of the logger. In your case that is `Loggable.whoAmI`. The class that is instantiated is of type `hu.jonas.simple.Service`, but since the method is on `Loggable` that is what shows up. That information is usually retrieved by looking through the stack trace.

In the example below, you will get the same results by pulling the stack trace yourself:

```
trait Loggable { 
  val logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  def whoAmI = {
    val stackTrace = Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace();
    logger.info("Class: %s, Method: %s".format(stackTrace(1).getClassName, 
      stackTrace(1).getMethodName))
    logger.info(this.getClass.getName)
  }
}
```

That will yield the output:

```
Jan 25, 2013 9:39:28 AM $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$Loggable$class whoAmI
INFO: Class: $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$Loggable$class, Method: whoAmI

Jan 25, 2013 9:39:28 AM $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$Loggable$class whoAmI
INFO: $line100.$read$$iw$$iw$Service
```

Which you can see is consistent with what Logger is displaying. If you continue to descend down the stack, you will see you can get at the call hierarchy with `stackTrace(3)` eventually yielding:

```
Jan 25, 2013 9:43:58 AM $line107.$read$$iw$$iw$Loggable$class whoAmI
INFO: Class: $line108.$read$$iw$$iw$Service, Method: answer
```

I am not sure exactly how to change that with `java.util.Logger` but as was specified in the other answer - perhaps using a formatter can get you the desired output. Otherwise, you could try another logging engine or roll your own with the information above.